# Continuing summation till the magnitude of the terms become smaller than a value

Tags: summation

I've tried to plot the below density plot. But since there is a summation inside the plot and the term inside the summation goes to zero differently for different values of $a$ and $t$, I need to tell the summation that continues till the value of the term inside the summation becomes smaller than a certain value say $0.01$. How can I do that?

```
     DensityPlot[
         Sum[(a^(1 + 2 mz) Sin[(3 + 2 mz) t]), {mz, 0, 100}], {a, 0.1, 0.2}, {t, 0, Pi/2}]
```

Comment: In the `Sum`, the summation variable `m` does not appear in the `Sum`. Is the variable supposed to be `mz` or should `mz` actually be `m*z`? Since you are plotting, what values are you using for the undefined parameters (e.g., `p1`)?

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the code @BobHanlon

Comment: `Nest` and `FixedPoint` might be worth mentioning.

Comment: How should I use them? @CarlLange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A procedural method is just to make a function of a while loop.

```
whilesum[a_, t_] := Block[
  {mz = 0., 
   term = (-16 a^(2 + 4 mz) - 8 (-1)^mz a^(1 + 2 mz) (Sin[(3 + 2 mz) t] - Sin[t - 2 mz t]))/((-1 + a^(2 + 4 mz)) (1 + 2 mz) \[Pi]), 
   total = 0.},
  While[
   term >= 0.01,
   total += total + term;
   mz++
  ];
  total
]

DensityPlot[
 whilesum[a, t],
 {a, 0.1, 0.2},
 {t, 0, Pi/2}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: When I run your code, I just get a blue totally blue plot with some white regions!

Comment: @Marco Woops, thanks for the catch!  I changed `expr` to `term` at the last minute and missed one.

Comment: Thanks, Could you please modify the term? I edited the term in the question so that the question seems more general.